# where-object not displaying data

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

**Question**: Why the `PowerShell` code1 below correctly displays data but code2 (with `where-object`) does not display any data (no errors but no output). Both have exact same subscripionID and storage account name? What I may be missing and how can it be corrected?

**Code1**:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourcegroups/storage-test-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storagetest0122"
```

**Code2**:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-Object {$_.Scope -eq "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourcegroups/storage-test-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storagetest0122"}
```

**UPDATE**:
Strange: When I tested the same code2 by changing subscription and storage account to a different subscription and a different storage account in that subscription, the code2 worked as expected. The only difference I see between the two scenarios is the following: For brevity, let's say subscription and storage account where code2 is not working are MySubscription and MyStorageAccount. Few months ago, MyStorageAccount was moved from a different subscription to MySubscription. [Ref: [Move resource to a different subscription]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription). Maybe this migration is causing the code2 to not work - or maybe migration process was not correctly followed.

Comment: Is the `Scope` property a simple string, or a more complicated object?  Maybe the thing you are trying to compare is actually a property (say, `Id`) of this object, so you may need to do something like this: `Where-Object {$_.Scope.Id -eq "<scope-details>"}`.  Use `Get-Member` to see more details: `(Get-AzRoleAssignment)[0].Scope | Get-Member`

Comment: You are performing a query and the query is not returning any data.  Try following to debug : Get-AzRoleAssignment | Format-List

Comment: @boxdog: Judging by the [`Get-AzRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleassignment?view=azps-11.2.0) docs, the outputs objects are of type `PSRoleAssignment`, and that type's [`.Scope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.resources.models.authorization.psroleassignment.scope?view=az-ps-latest#microsoft-azure-commands-resources-models-authorization-psroleassignment-scope) property is  `[string]`-typed

Comment: In __Code2__, are you `Set-AzContext -Subscription xxxx-xxxx-xxx` before running `Get-AzRoleAssignment` ? Already tested and I'm unable to reproduce, as long as your context is in that subscription and you have Reader permissions over `storagetest0122` to see the RBAC, you should get output.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes, I'm in the correct context. Both code1 and code2 are using exact same subscriptionId and storage account - and code1 works. Few minutes ago, I added an **UPDATE** section that you may want to read.